# How do I get 2 table data in one mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Well, In mysql database  there 2 table.

**a) users** table structure

```
------------------------
id            user_email
------------------------
1             email1@yahoo.com
2             email2@yahoo.com
3             email3@yahoo.com
6             email6@yahoo.com
7             email7@yahoo.com
9             email9@yahoo.com
```

**b) user_property**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
property_id    user_id   pcode    pvalue    paddress    psuburb  creation_date
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10             1         11205    $100      address      suburb   10-02-2014 
11             2         11205    $100      address      suburb   10-02-2014
12             3         11205    $100      address      suburb   10-02-2014
13             10        11205    $100      address      suburb   10-02-2014
14             12        11205    $100      address      suburb   10-02-2014
```

So in users table there are user **email address** exists. So I want to get few **user_property** table data with email address from **users** table. But how do I get it with a single mysql query ?

```
$sql =  mysql_query("select user_id, postcode, paddress, psuburb, pvalue, creation_date FROM 
user_property ORDER BY property_id DESC");
```

In my **users** table email address field name is **user_email** and id field name is **id**.

Comment: By using `JOIN` ?

Comment: as @Mr.Alien say, if you don't know how to , this is the tutorial `http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp`

Comment: You may also use the UNION operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am giving the answer of your question on some assumption basis, try to implement it with your query, Use [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) :

```
$sql =  mysql_query("select u.*, up.postcode, up.paddress FROM users as u JOIN users_property as up on u.email=up.user_email ORDER BY up.property_id DESC");
```

Assumptions are:

- There are 2 tables `users` and `users_property` .
- Your users table has some fields and users_property have postcode,
  address, etc..
- You can add the fields name if you want to retrieve it from 
  `users_property`.

Updated Answer:

```
$sql =  mysql_query("select u.id,up.* FROM users as u JOIN users_property as up on u.email=up.user_email ORDER BY up.property_id DESC");
```

Comment: I'm trying it. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my question. Please check it. Actualy I want to get all data from user_property table with email address from users table.

Comment: see my updated answer , now query will fetch the whole data from `user_property` and id from users.

Comment: It's doesn't return any data.

Comment: I dont understand why it's not return any data with your query. For your better understand I'm again explaining the query. I want to get all data from user_property table (note: there is no email field) and email address from users table which match the user_property.user_id = users.id

Comment: what the meaning of "all date" in `user_property` table? , not return any data because not matching data. Could you fill some data example in user_property table on your question

Comment: @Krofz I just updated my questions. Sorry typo, it's should be `All data`. Now you you can see that in user_property table there are 3 `user_id` which match the users table `id` which is (1, 2, 3) I want to get all data from user_property and email from users table which match the `user_property.userid` = `users.id`

Comment: @Babu : Try `FROM users as u JOIN users_property as up on u.id = up.user_id`